# function not invoked in file transfer in TCP client/server program

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

function read_and_send is not getting called, no error message. Basically what I am trying to do is that I want to communicate between concurrent server and client programs. Client will request for a file , server will check if the file is available, then it will check if the file size < 1000 bytes, then just send the file to user, but if file size >= 1000 bytes then server will compress it and transfer to the client.

What I have done is that client enters the file name and, server passes the file_name and communication_socket to a function (which is causing problem). That function finds the length of the file and execute accordingly.

I am using ubuntu 13.10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void read_and_send(char *file_name, int comm_sock);
bool compress_file(char *file, char *new_file);

int main()
{
    char *msg, *data;
    struct in_addr addr;
    int conn_sock,comm_sock,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;
    conn_sock= socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port=htons(1234);       // @
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bind(conn_sock,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));

    listen(conn_sock,10);
    while(true)
    {
        comm_sock = accept(conn_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t *)&client_addr);
        cout<<"Conection Established\n\n";

        if(fork()==0)
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                data=new char[100];
                n= read(comm_sock,data,100);    
                cout<<" Data Recieved : ";
                cout<<data<<endl;

                if((strcmp(data,"QUIT")==0) || (strcmp(data,"quit")==0))
                {
                    break;
                }

                cout<<" Input : ";
                read_and_send(data, comm_sock);         // not getting called

                /* if I execute this (i.e: for simple communicating with text messages, then everything goes fine. 
                msg=new char[100];
                cin.getline(msg,100,'\n');
                write(comm_sock,msg,100);
                */
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            close(comm_sock);
        }
    }   
    delete []data;
    delete []msg;
    close(conn_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

**read_and_send() :**

```
void read_and_send(char *file_name, int comm_sock)               //server_side
{
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open(file_name);

    if(myReadFile)
    {
        char *output;
        if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
        {
            myReadFile.seekg (0, myReadFile.end);
            int length = myReadFile.tellg();
            myReadFile.seekg (0, myReadFile.beg);

            if(length < 1000)
            {
                output = new char[length];
                if(!myReadFile.eof()) 
                {
                    myReadFile >> output;
                    write(comm_sock,output,length);
                }
                myReadFile.close();
            }
            else
            {
                char new_file[] = "compressed.txt";
                myReadFile.close();
                bool is_compressed = compress_file(file_name, new_file);
                ifstream f;
                f.open(new_file);
                if(f)
                {
                    f.seekg (0, f.end);
                    int compressed_length = f.tellg();
                    f.seekg (0, f.beg);

                    output = new char[compressed_length];
                    if(!f.eof())
                    {
                        f >> output;
                        write(comm_sock,output,length); 
                    }
                }
                else
                    cout<<"read_and_send: Error opening compressed file";
            }
            delete[] output;    // deallocating, dynamically allocated resources 
        }
        else
            cout<<"read_and_send: Error opening file";
    }
    else
        cout<<"read_and_send: file don't exists";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are blocking in the preceding read(), which means that the peer isn't sending anything. NB you need to check the result of read() for both zero and -1.

Comment: when I don't invoke read_and_send function, and just make client/server chat then it's all okay, so it means that it's not the problem with that read command.